# Container Div won't work

Tags: html, css

Here is the problem: the Whole2 element in the css portion is supposed to be a container for the other divs, but it doesn't create the border or padding around he other elements. If anyone can tell me what I am doing wrong, please do.

By the way, the content is nonsense, ignore it.

This is my css:

```
    <style>
.Whole2{
    border:4px solid black;
    padding: 1em;
}
.Title{
    border: 1px solid;
    background: lightblue;
    text-align: right;
    width: 57.9em;
    height: 8em;
    padding: .5em;
}
.Subtitle {
   font-size: 0.8em;
}
.Blog1 {
    width: 44em;
    height: 20em;
    border:1px solid black;
    background: lightgreen;
    text-align: justify;
    padding: .5em;

}

.Blog2 {
    width: 44em;
    height: 20em;
    border:1px solid black;
    background: lightgreen;
    text-align: justify;
    padding: .5em;
}
.Friends {
    border:1px solid black;
    background: purple;
    width: 12em;
    height: 12em;
    position: absolute;
    top:10em;
    left:0.5em;
    padding: .5em;
}
.clears{
    clear: both;
}
.theImg{
    float: right;
    padding: .5em;
}
.Blogs{
    position: absolute;
    top:10em;
    left:14.4em;
}
.blogtext{
    font-size: 18px;
}
.Whole2 {
    border:4px solid black;
    padding: 1em;
}

</style>
```

This is my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="lab1.css">
   <div class="Whole2">
      <head>
         <div Class="Title">
            <h1> Title thing </h1>
         <div class="Subtitle">
            <h2> Subtitle thing </h2>
         </div>
         </div>
      </head>

   <h3 class="clears"></h3>

   <div class="Friends">
      <head>
         <h1> Friends</h1>
      </head>
      <body>
         <table>
            <th>
               Friends
            </th>
            <tr>
               <td>
                  Leo Bloom
               </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>
                  Leo Bloom
               </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>
                  Leo Bloom
               </td>
            </tr>
         </table>
   </body>
   </div>



   <h3 class="clears"></h3>

   <div class="Blogs">

   <div class="Blog1">
   <head>
      <h1> <span><time>2015-02-11</time></span>: Moose Day</h1>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="theImg">
   <img src="http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMjE0ODk2NjczOV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTYwNDQ0NDg4._V1_SY317_CR4,0,214,317_AL_.jpg" height="200" width="200">
      </div>
      <h2>
      <div class="blogtext">
      The moose (North America) or elk (Europe), Alces alces, is the largest extant species in the deer family. Moose are distinguished by the palmate antlers of the males; other members of the family have antlers with a dendritic ("twig-like") configuration. Moose typically inhabit boreal and mixed deciduous forests of the Northern Hemisphere in temperate to subarctic climates. Moose used to have a much wider range but hunting and other human activities greatly reduced it over the years. Moose have been reintroduced to some of their former habitats. Currently, most moose are found in Canada, Alaska, Scandinavia and Russia. 
      </div>
      </h2>
   </body>
   </div>

   <h3 class="clears"></h3>

   <div class="Blog2">
   <head>
      <h1> <span><time>2015-03-11</time></span>: Second Moose Day</h1>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="theImg">
      <img src="http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMjE0ODk2NjczOV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTYwNDQ0NDg4._V1_SY317_CR4,0,214,317_AL_.jpg" height="200" width="200">
      </div>
      <h2>
      <div class="blogtext">
      Their diet consists of both terrestrial and aquatic vegetation. The most common moose predators are wolves, bears, and humans. Unlike most other deer species, moose are solitary animals and do not form herds. Although generally slow-moving and sedentary, moose can become aggressive and move surprisingly quickly if angered or startled. Their mating season in the autumn can lead to spectacular fights between males competing for a female.
      </div>
      </h2>

   </body>
   </div>
   </div>
   </div>


</html>
```

Comment: That HTML is invalid.. you have multiple `<head>`/`<body>` elements.

Comment: Problem #1 is that your HTML is totally invalid.

Comment: `<head>` and `<body>` don't work as you are trying to make them. The `<head>` tag contains page metadata that is not shown. The `<body>` contains the markup that is actually shown.

Comment: You should only have one set of `<head>` & `<body>` tags. Once you correct that, your container `<div>` should be within the `<body>` tag.

Comment: Thank you everyone, I copied and pasted code over and over and this is what happens. Thank you for pointing this out.

Answer (score 0):

First, put `<div class="Whole2">` inside the body.
Second, you only can have one `<head>` and one `<body>`. And I think that you are confounding `<head>` with `<header>`.